# docker-compose make requests between containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm a bit new to docker-compose, so I'm not so sure what am I looking for even.

I created two images, and I'm running them using docker-compose, on a local environment these two services communicate via HTTP requests (both are running on localhost, one service on port 3000, one service on port 8000)

When I moved those two services to docker (two separated containers and images) I can't seem to make them communicate.

this is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  service1:
    image: services/services1
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    links:
      - "service2"
    depends_on:
      - service2

  service2:
    image: services/service2
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

When I'm making http requests directly to each of the services I get a good response, but when I'm making a request to service1 and in services1 I have another request to service 2, I can't get a response at all

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Both services are running on 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> so I'm not so sure what am I looking for even.

Most probably you are looking for this part of [the docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/). It explains how docker compose is treating network. Part of particular interest for you is this:

```
By default Compose sets up a single network for your app.
Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable
by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them 
at a hostname identical to the container name.
```

Meaning that you should use service1 and service2 instead of localhost to target across services.

Comment: So just to make sure I understood, because what I didn't is not completely working for me, if I'm using JS for example, I should do something like this `axios.get('http://service2/api/status')` ?

Comment: or substitute `service2` with`service2:8000` in case you use designated ports, yes...

Comment: I had the exact same issue between two containers running with the same compose. One service called 'web' was exposing a 'localhost:3000' and the other one was supposed to run tests requesting on 'localhost:3000'. The issue was resolved by requesting on 'web:3000'. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

All the services declared in the docker-compose.yml file are running in their own container. They have different ips. You can address them with their service name that will resolve to the service ip.
In your case:

```
docker-compose exec service1 ping service2
or
docker-compose exec service2 ping service1
```

Answer (score 7):

You should define a network and use the name of the service instead of localhost:

```
version: '3'

services:
  service1:
    image: services/services1
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    links:
      - "service2"
    depends_on:
      - service2
    networks:
      - mynet

  service2:
    image: services/service2
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    networks:
      - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
```

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where your configuration is correct, but there is happening that you have a CORS issues.

In my case I was using react-js in my frontend service, so I added a proxy in `package.json` file.

```
...
"proxy": "http://{container_name}:80/api",
...
```